# ADF_FACES-60097

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am creating a school management application using Oracle ADF. I have one Student Result page where we can add the result for each student. Here is the image of the same:

[Student's Result Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8t2X.jpg)

When I change say the Result Year, I get an exception like:

<oracle.adf.view>  <_logUnhandledException> <ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4>
oracle.jbo.domain.DataCreationException: JBO-25009: Cannot create an object of type:java.lang.Integer from type:java.lang.String with value:Pass

Don't Understand this only the student id is number, all other 3 attributes are string only.
Can anyone help?

Below is the Jsff Code:

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.ResultStudentResultView.hints.ResultYear.name}" 
filterable="true" sortable="true" 
headerText="#{bindings.ResultStudentResultView.hints.ResultYear.label}" 
id="c7"> 
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{row.bindings.ResultYear.inputValue}" 
label="#{row.bindings.ResultYear.label}" 
required="#{bindings.ResultStudentResultView.hints.ResultYear.mandatory}" 
shortDesc="#{bindings.ResultStudentResultView.hints.ResultYear.tooltip}" 
id="soc2"> 
<f:selectItems value="#{row.bindings.ResultYear.items}" id="si2"/> 
<f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.ResultYear.validator}"/> 
</af:selectOneChoice> 
</af:column>
```

Comment: seems your result column is a string LoV for database column of type int. check your lov implementation that it uses the proper key of type int instead of string on the view object. it could also be that you linked the wrong key in the lov implementation, so check that as well.

Comment: Hi. The result column is a static LOV with only one column, there is no Key attribute. Just the Years as a static list

Comment: What is the value for result column in database? Post the attribute and LOV definition  for result from view object and jsff code

Comment: Hi. The result column is Varchar2(20). The LOV is static one with three values Pass, fail, on hold. Added the jsff code in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is with the column **Result**, check what is the attribute type in view object and if corresponding default value is given as literal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi. The View and Entity Object is of type String and there is no default value only Literal is selected in the View Object, but no value is there